# Release Management - Build Fails when I set 'Build Configurations' in Build Definition

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management, web.config-transform

I hope I do a good enough job of explaining this. I am attempting to use Web.Config transformations to maintain the datasource in my connection string across various platforms. I have it working to the point where the web.release.config is updating through the build process (i.e. it changes to test server at testing, then dev server at dev) - however I am unable to get this web.release.config to actually update the web.config.

I have followed several tutorials to the word and I (think I) have pinned the issue down to the Build Definitions --> Process --> 2. Build --> Confirgurations. All the tutorials say to put "Any CPU / Release" there... However when I do that my build fails stating that it cannot find the _PublishedSites folder within the build folder (or deployer user does not have access - however i think its the former as this _PublishedSites folder does not exist for the builds that fail.

However if I just remove the values in the Build Configurations then it builds with no errors, but only the web.release.config file is updated with the variable.

Has anyone else overcome this issue... I guess I could just update the web.config instead of the web.release.config - however I dont want to have to keep switching between connection strings when switching between debugand build.

-- *********** Edited for Clarity on my issue ***********

To clarify what I am trying to do - I have setup the **web.release.config** with the following:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="IRISConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=__ConnString__; Initial Catalog=..."
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So that when the project is initially built - the web.config is updated with the above - including the tokanized place holder for the DataSource. This means that by the time the web.config gets to RM (Release Management) the new web.config will have the

```
Data Source=__ConnString__
```

replaced with the variables from the RM Component - e.i. the testing server for testing stage and development server for the development stage etc..

My build definition is configured to build to a Drop Folder and under the Process area I have the following setup:

[image]

However when I try to build through RM I get the error:
[image]
This is true as the build hasnt got so far as creating the _PublishedWebsites folder. This seems to be something to do with the value in the Build Definition **2, Build --> 2, Configurations = Any CPU/Release** because if I take this out - it builds but the web.config does not get updated with the tokenized info from the web.release.config.

I hope that helps illustrates my issue any better... i have found a few examples online where this seems to be working but just cant crack the nut my end!

Comment: Are you using TFS Release Management or just the TFS Build?

Comment: TFS MS Release Management - so the build is controlled within Release Management.

Comment: The build should trigger the TFS Release Management (not the other way); during the release to various stages you should apply different config files.

Comment: Yeah, the way I think this is meant to work is that the web.release.config file contains the token value (with double underscores either side). When the project is therefore built the connection string in web.config is replaced with the release.config value  - the token value. So by the time the web.config gets to RM it contains the tokenized placeholder. Then, when RM picks it up it applies the variables from the component and the job is done. It all makes sense in theory but am getting this strange error when applying to practice.

Answer (score 3):

Web.config transformations don't really work in conjunction with the Release Management paradigm.

The problem is simple: Web.config transforms occur at the time of build, based on the configuration you build. This means that you have to build for each configuration in order to get the transforms to trigger.

This is a fundamentally incompatible approach to how Release Management functions. RM is based on **one build** that you then release (and test!) through a pipeline of environments. This means that you only get one opportunity to perform a config transform.

Agent-based RM functions on the idea of config file tokenization and token replacement. What I've had success doing is using a config transform to insert the tokens, then use RM to replace them per-environment.

So, let's say you have web.config that looks like this:

`<connectionString name="myApp" value="SomeLocalConnectionString">`

You set up a config transform to replace `SomeLocalConnectionString` with a *token*:

`<connectionString name="myApp" value="__ConnectionString__">`

Then, when you configure your release, you use the Configuration Variables section of your RM component to specify that it should look in the web.config file and locate the `ConnectionString` token. For each stage in your release template where you use that component, you can specify a concrete value, which will then be set during the actual release process.

Comment: Thanks for the details there Daniel... This was going to be my initial approach until someone said I should look at doing it this way:

Comment: (sorry - entered early)... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager.aspx

Comment: The idea being that the Release Management will take care of the Connection Strings from the Web.Release.Config and your web.config is left as is for debugging.

Comment: So I think it is using the functionality you mentioned above to its advantage in so much that the the build is supposed to change the web.config so that it is given the tokenized value __ConStr__ so by the time it gets to RM it is in the state you have mentioned above... RM Will then use this token to apply the variables scoped within the component.

Comment: See my blog post [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-preparing-deployment-pipeline/) for specific advice on how to achieve the result described by Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Transformations do work in conjunction with rm. why is it important ? say you have a qa web.config which has a tracing tag , which you want to completely remove from production because you want less verbosity. you cannot use place holders to remove entire tags or add them , transformations is the only tech that does that for you , in case you do not want to write a plugin to visual studio by yourself...

but there are a few bugs in rm release template relating transformations , and i had to investigate the issue myself , cause no one would know what to do there .

it's true that setting the configurations to release is shutting down rm, make sure your release template is updated and is only - ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml.

ms build arguments- 
/p:PublishProfile=YourPublishProfileName /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:OutputPath=bin\Release (set this for the error of output path not set)
Set publish profile to build both builds for both configurations before rm intervention because /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true messes with the order of things .

Set build section (number 2 in build definition) to as much configurations as needed 
Any CPU|QA,Any CPU|Release

you can build 1 .csproj , using 2 or more configurations no problem .

in configurations to release (section 6 at build definition) set only the last configuration in the chain (Any CPU|Release) , if you don't RM will release twice the same build for no reason (3 times if you have 3 configurations etc.)

make sure to use a valid checked in to TFS publish profile(right click a website - publish, set your desired publish settings i.e. precompiled\compiled \ emit debugging etc.)publish profile should be with a one word name (or else it will through an exception you are using more than one publish profile), which is kind of great , because in the publish profile you can do what ever kind of publish you want , and even maintain compatibility to precompiled sites ,which already exists from former manual deployments , include pdb's if you like and such (very powerful option) .

this is about it,  you can use almost the same configuration for a windows service (app.config) using slow cheetah with the msbuild arguments like :
/p:OutputPath=bin\Release /p:DebugSymbols=true